# Editing video frames in exo player

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I have an encoded video stream that I'm playing through exoplayer. What I want to do is get each frame of the video and edit it before it is displayed (e.g. changing some pixels).

Is it possible to do this with exoplayer? I've been looking at the implementation of MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java in the exoplayer source, but it seems that each MediaCodec releases its output buffer to a surface itself, without possibility of editing the frame before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on exactly what you want to modify, but it is possible to use a GLSurface view and listen for each frame and then transform the frame, assuming it is not encrypted (with encrypted you van usually still apply transformation bit you definitely should not be able to read the frame itself).

There is a good example project which does something similar to apply filters to videos, extending ExoPlayer - take a look at the EPlayerRenderer class in particular.

- https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/ExoPlayerFilter

You can also do a similar thing with openCV - read in a frame, modify it and then display it. This may be easier if you are doing compilacted image manipulations.